# Open Closed and Interface Segregation

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I am writing a code which basically reads a text file (Tabular format) and check if the file contains expected data type or not. For that I have write following class.

The sample file would be something like this.

```
name    age
abc     20
xyz     vf
aaa     22
```

And I have JSON file which says, which conlumn should contains what?

```
{
    filename:"test.txt",
    cols:{
            name:string,
            age: int
    }

}
```

A **JSON** file contains the DataType for each row, so I know what to expect?

Following code working without any issue. However, it seems that this code Violates the open closed and interface segregation principle.

```
public class DataValidation {

    public boolean isInt(String value) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean isFloat(String value) {
        try {
            Float.parseFloat(value);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And so I am thinking to Refector the code as mentioned below.  However, would like to know what advantage I will get and is there any better approach?

```
public interface DataValidation {

    boolean validate(String value);
}

public class IntValidator implements DataValidation {
    public boolean validate(String value) {
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(value);
            return true;
        }catch (NumberFormatException ne){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Em.... you wanna get rid off declaration types of JSON fields or what? Please, provide  example.

Comment: Not sure I understand your last question. Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: Are your Data Types limited to primitive data types or more?

Comment: @Green_Wizard I am trying to understand if there is a better approach to refecor the code. I have an alternate solution however, I still have to write a logic to match which function to call for each cell.

Comment: @Gholamali-Irani yes all the data types are limited to primitive data types only.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing where and how the `DataValidation` is used. Please, show us how it's used.

Comment: @SergiiBishyr  I have to put all these value in hadoop hdfc, so letter on I can use with spark. I want to create a error file which contains record with mismatch record. If I directly put in hadoop, this record will be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic Definition of Open-Close Principle (OCP)**: (Meyer 1988)
the open/closed principle states "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification"; that is, such an entity can **allow its behavior to be extended without modifying its source code**. [see Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

**BUT**: On the other hand **Uncle Bob** in [this reference](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/12/TheOpenClosedPrinciple.html) provide some clarifications about the meaning of OCP. (that I used them in the following)

**First of all:** In my idea, your class (`DataValidation`) **did not conflict** 
Open-Close Principle.

Your class **JUST** check the primitive data types. (as you answered to my question in comment). There are **just 8 primitive data types** in Java. **This number will not change in the future.** So if you put all the 8 methods in one class, you don't have any extensions or modifications on data types in the future. 
In the other hand, OCP is about adding new source codes without any changes in old codes. So event if Java adds new data type, you can add the method easily without modifications in other parts of code.

**Therefore**, I think that your class is not BIG enough to violate Open-Close Principle.

**Secondly**: To use Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) 
To use ISP, **we need some prerequisites**. We should have some dependencies between part of our system (or class). we should **need for Dependency Management** to manage some parts of system and we consciously decide what each part of the system can depend on. [please read this reference in-depth](https://dzone.com/articles/hard-rocking-with-interface-segregation-principle)

I think that your class is **just a Checker class** and does not have any states (Attributes or Fields). So there is not any reason to use ISP.

**To sum up**: Using all Object Oriented principles and heuristics (like SOLID), should help us to **reduce COMPLEXITY**. In your project, there is no need to use them.

**To offer a solution for your problem**
You can use an `enum DataTypes {boolean, char, _etc_}` for Primitive Data Types and use only one method like `DataType getDataType(String S)` to get the type of given `String` as `enum`. **But** your approach (`DataValidation class`) is good enough too.

Answer (score 0):

Gholamali-Irani provide great answer, but I want add some my own thinks about yours  topic:

First of all, almost every best practice, paradigm, etc. trying to increase degree of maintainability, testability and extensibility. Do you really need them? How big probability of adding some custom and complex type? If its  very low, than maybe your first variant is good enough for your task (not for general task of verification, just for yours).

Secondly, much depends on how you use it. You didn't show how exactly you use all this methods/classes/interfaces. "Servant" code might be very good, it can cleanest code in the world,  but who cares if its used incorrectly or its very hard to use?